# How to get timezone string from javascript Date object?

Tags: javascript, date

I've a requirement where I have to show the Date timestamp in following format.

MM:DD:YYYY HH:MM:SS IST/CST/CDT.

I have used javascript date object to get the date and time. But I don't know how to get the timezone (IST or CST or CDT or etc) from the obj. Do we have any technique or native javascript Plugin (non-jQuery plugin) to get this timezone abbreviated value?

Answer (score 1):

Check out moment.js library and [its format method](http://momentjs.com/timezone/docs/#/using-timezones/formatting/), with which you can format a date to include the time zone.

Comment: You can use momentjs and jstimezone https://github.com/raulferras/jstimezone , but I suggest reading this excellent article too: http://joshowens.me/dealing-with-timezones-in-javascript/

Answer (score 1):

Below is pure JS code, without using any third party library

```
var x = new Date();

var tz = x.toTimeString().match(/\((.+)\)/)[1];

var month = x.getMonth() + 1;
month = month < 10 ? ('0' + month) : month.toString();

var date = x.getDate() < 10 ? ('0' + x.getDate()) : x.getDate().toString();

var hour = x.getHours() < 10 ? ('0' + x.getHours()) : x.getHours().toString();

var min = x.getMinutes() < 10 ? ('0' + x.getMinutes()) : x.getMinutes().toString();

var sec = x. getSeconds() < 10 ? ('0' + x.getSeconds()) : x.getSeconds().toString();

var output = month + ':' + date + ':' + x.getFullYear() + ' ' + hour + ':' + min + ':' + sec + ' ' + tz
```

Comment: this is what I coded. Lately I found the Date object will give diff kind of string in IE. This code works perfectly in Chrome.

Comment: Which IE version are you using??

Comment: It should work. What output are you getting for toTimestring()?

Comment: Output from chrome: "19:39:25 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)"
Output from IE11: "19:40:08 UTC+0530"

Comment: 19:42:47 GMT+0530 (IST). this is the output I get for toTimeString() on chrome. and the full code gives "11:17:2015 19:42:16 IST"

Comment: It works fine with Chrome. Problem is with IE only. :(